# Understanding of andengine texture load

Tags: android, textures, andengine

I am trying to understand below code from andengine to load the texture, i would like to know what is 512 n 512(i know its height and width), but the image of size 480 * 320.

```
public void onLoadResources() {
    this.mTexture = new Texture(512, 512,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mSplashTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.mTexture,this, "image.png", 0, 0);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
}
```

I searched on the net but no expected explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know well AndEngine but this might be because a lot of libs assume that images dimension are power of two.

Here you can find a better explanation:
[About power of 2 rule](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/textures/make-better-textures-correct-size-and-power-of-two.php).

Comment: Thanks jDourlens, i wasnt aware of this rule. :)

Comment: I know this was really hard while programing on PSP ;)